# jquery run function by KeyUp instead of submit

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I've got this code which checks if an url is a valid url.

Right now the check is done by the press of a button. But I want to get rid of the button and instead just do the check when the user types something in the textbox or when he's done typing.

How can I achieve this? I am not at all familiar with jquery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});;
</script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    }
  }
});
  });
  </script>
  <style>#field { margin-left: .5em; float: left; }
    #field, label { float: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small; }
    br { clear: both; }
    input { border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: .5em;  }
    input.error { border: 1px solid red; }
    label.error {
        background: url('http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/demo/images/unchecked.gif') no-repeat;
        padding-left: 16px;
        margin-left: .3em;
    }
    label.valid {
        background: url('http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/demo/images/checked.gif') no-repeat;
        display: block;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
    }
</style>


<form id="myform">
  <label for="field">Required, URL: </label>
  <input class="left" id="field" name="field" OnKeyUp="$("#myform").validate"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
</form>
```

Comment: What have try so far?  And what is the question ?

Comment: How do you want to tell when the user done typing? Text size? On blur? Key up would cause it to validate on every single key (unless you specify that it is when the user press an specific key, like Enter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the code below. I guess this is what you need.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});;
</script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    }
  }
});

$("#field").keyup(function(){
$('#myform').valid();
});
  });
  </script>
  <style>#field { margin-left: .5em; float: left; }
    #field, label { float: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small; }
    br { clear: both; }
    input { border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: .5em;  }
    input.error { border: 1px solid red; }
    label.error {
        background: url('http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/demo/images/unchecked.gif') no-repeat;
        padding-left: 16px;
        margin-left: .3em;
    }
    label.valid {
        background: url('http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/demo/images/checked.gif') no-repeat;
        display: block;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
    }
</style>


<form id="myform">
  <label for="field">Required, URL: </label>
  <input class="left" id="field" name="field"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `change()` that is described in this page

http://api.jquery.com/change/

to catch when you change the text in the input field and then click away and afterwards apply your validator.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to evaluate a single element with the `element` method on validator:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $validator = $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            field: {
                required: true,
                url: true
            }
        }
    });

    $("#field").keyup(function () {
        $validator.element(this);
    });
});
```

This will validate `#field` on every `keyup` event.

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bp8wP/